# Is there a Github API to list issues with logical OR of labels?

Tags: github, github-api, github-issues

The [API call to list issues by labels](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/issues/issues?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-repository-issues) by default return issues with all mentioned labels included, ie. logical AND of labels. For example: `curl https://api.github.com/orgs/ORG/issues?labels=bug,ui,@high` return issues with ALL three labels, `bug`, `ui` and `@high`.

There seems to be no way to list issues with ANY of the mentioned labels (the logical OR). Strangely this [feature](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-08-02-search-issues-by-label-using-logical-or) is available in GitHub's UI issue search bar.

The labels targeted are mutually exclusive (similar to `Sev 1`, `Sev 2`, ...). Currently I'm making one API call for each of the 'N' labels. This solves the problem, but is obviously not optimal! Any help would be appreciated!

PS: There are way more labels used in the repository. So listing issues without certain labels isn't an option. Also the labels do not follow any string patterns, so any regex methods, if any, wouldn't help much.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.